# Failed upgrade from ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel, 19.04, 19.10

I tried upgrading from ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10 and my laptop accidentally shut down. Now when I try to run 19.10, I get "kernel panic- not syncing: VFS unable to mount". I get the same error when I try to run it in recovery mode. I tried running kernel of ubuntu 19.04, but the screen blacks out and there is the only cursor. I tried running recovery mode of ubuntu 19.04 and ran the command "apt-get -f install" or any command related to apt-get, I get "you must manually run sudo dpkg --configured -a" even though I have run the command multiple times. I am not able to run any command. When I run ubuntu 19.04 in failsafe graphic mode, there is only black screen.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use "Rescatux & Super Grub2 Disk"

https://www.supergrubdisk.org/

Note: ESC shows the Grub menu on system, not SHIFT.

To show console use CTRL+ALT+F1 to load the TTY1 console.